# Is there a way to get the location from carrier without data connection in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, geolocation, android-location

I Would like to show the location of user by fetching the location from carrier(cell network) without data connection in Android App. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to get lat and lng using network or gps?

Comment: I want to get the location name from cell network without internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

you can get location from cell network by getting LAC and CID value.

```
final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
    final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        String LAC= location.getLac() ;
        String CID= location.getCid();
    }
}
```

In manifest add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Now post this value in this site. [cellphonetrackers](http://cellphonetrackers.org/gsm/gsm-tracker.php) you will get the latitude and longitude. If you want to send your location, you can send SMS with this information. But if you want to show your location on device you must need internet connection.

Comment: I am looking to show the location on device without internet connection.